# Does TFS 2018 build not support testrunconfig files for settings?

Tags: unit-testing, tfsbuild

We are in the process of testing a migration to TFS 2018 SP1 from TFS 2012.  Our test settings are in a testrunconfig file which works just fine locally and on the current build server.  However, I'm trying to run the tests on TFS 2018 and it looks like it only supports the testsettings and runsettings files.  VS2017, however, seems to accept all three.  Is this testrunconfig file type just not supported any longer?  I can't find any documentation from MS about it.

Comment: The actual markup in the testrunconfig file looks just like the testsettings file.  So I'm not sure that there really is a difference?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this "restrunconfig" file is actually a "testsettings" file with a different extension.